# String tokenizer to token a phone number

Tags: java, regex

Can you help me tokenize a user input for a phone number in the following format: xxx xxx-xxxx  in the first else if

The regular expression has been validated to work correctly. I will include it.

To follow the same procedure i have with the rest of the phone numbers i want to grab
the first 3 digits into a seperate variable and the rest to concatenate.

Here is the code

```
else  if (ValidatePhone.validateSpaceAfterAreaCode(input)) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
      String token = st.nextToken("\\s").toString();
      //  firstdigits =  new Long(st.nextToken("\\s")).toString();
        phoneNumber = new Long(st.nextToken("-")).toString();
        phoneNumber += new Long(st.nextToken("-")).toString();
        num = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "first digits: " + token + "\nlast digits: " + num);
    }
          //WORKING for xxx.xxx.xxxx

    else  if (ValidatePhone.validateAllPeriods(input)) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
        firstdigits =  new Long(st.nextToken(".")).toString();
        phoneNumber = new Long(st.nextToken(".")).toString();
        phoneNumber += new Long(st.nextToken(".")).toString();
        num = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "first digits: " + firstdigits + "\nlast digits: " + num);
    }
```

here is the function in the validate phone class

```
public static boolean validateSpaceAfterAreaCode(String acspace)
{
    return  acspace.matches("^[1-9]\\d{2}\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
}
```

Comment: is there anything we can do to help you?

Comment: You need to explain what you are having trouble with.  What's not working?

Comment: Is that xxx xxx-xxxx the format that you are enforcing for the input, or is that your assumption of how phone numbers are formatted? As valid phone numbers can include exit codes (I don't think people usually include this), country codes, and area codes which are different in size for different regions of the world.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this much more complex than it needs to be.  I'm guessing the allowable forms are

```
nnn nnn-nnnn
nnn-nnn-nnnn
nnn.nnn.nnnn
```

and that you don't want to allow other variations such as `nnn nnn.nnnn` or `nnn.nnn-nnnn`. Try this

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("([2-9]\\d{2})([-.])(\\d{3})\\2(\\d{4})");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("([2-9]\\d{2})(\\s)(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})");

Matcher m = p1.matcher(input);

if (!m.matches())
    m = p2.matcher(input)
if (m.matches()
{
    // results are in m.group(1), m.group(3) and m.group(4)
}
else
{
    // input didn't match
}
```

Explanation:

```
p1
  ([2-9]\\d{2})  - Areacode (first digit must be 2-9)
  ([-.])         - Delimiter, either a dot or hyphen
  (\\d{3})       - The 3-digit exchange
  \\2            - Back-reference to the first delimiter
  (\\d{4})       - The 4-digit number
```

The back-reference causes the regex to match whatever the first delimiter matched.

Pattern p2 is simple except I put capturing parentheses around the first delimiter so the indexes of the numeric groups would be the same in both cases, eliminating the need to check which pattern matched.

Answer (score 0):

I would just split it:

```
String parts = input.split("\\D+");
```

This splits using any sequence of non-digits and will create an array of size 3, which you can then parse into ints etc.